# git stash apply recovered only unstaged files

Tags: git, github, git-stash

I have some 24 files changed on branch A. None of these are committed. Some of these files with changes, say 18 are unstaged. And other 6 files are staged. I had to checkout to other branch B because of some other work.
I stashed these changes while on branch A, checked out to branch B, did my work and later checked back to branch A.
I now did git stash apply. I can only see changes that are unstaged are recovered, but there is no sign of file changes that are changed and staged.

Can anyone help how I can get these staged but uncommitted changes back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can :

- discard your current changes (for example : `git checkout .`),
- run `git stash apply --index`

---

When you create a stash (using `git stash`), git stores two snapshots of your repo : your current index (the state of the files that are currently staged) , and your current worktree (the state of the files on disk).

When you run `git stash apply`, it restores only the state of your worktree ; when you run `git stash apply --index`, it restores both the index (as it was when you stahed your changes) and the worktree.

In the situation you describe in your question : you stashed from branch `A`, and you returned to exactly that state before running `git stash apply`. You have therefore a 100% guarantee that no conflict will occur when applying your stash.

The small twist to the `--index` option is the following : if conflicts get in the way when running `git stash apply --index`, since git uses the index to store (and let you solve) conflicts, you won't really know if the conflicts come from the "index" part or the "worktree" part. Again : this doesn't apply to the situation you describe in your question.

Comment: what is the difference b/w git stash apply and git stash apply --index?

Comment: @ajayeswar: the difference is that with `--index`, Git applies the stashed index too.

Comment: Note that `--index` can fail (because there's no place to resolve conflicts). On the whole, it might be better to make a true commit than a stash when situations like this arise.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing clarity! I am able to recover the changes in the way I wanted . Like you righly pointed out, I had to undo the stash apply ,which I did first, and only then do git stash apply --index. Otherwise I got conflicts and no way to reslove them

Answer (score 1):

[LeGEC has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67473853/1256452) that you need to use `git stash apply --index`.  Here's why.

> I have some 24 files changed on branch A. None of these are committed. Some of these files with changes, say 18 are unstaged. And other 6 files are staged.

Worth pointing out: *staged* just means *updated in Git's index*.

Let's break this down a bit more.  A Git commit has two parts:

- One part of any given Git commit is metadata: information *about* the commit, such as who made it, when, and so on.  This is very useful, but is not important to you right now.
- The other part of that commit is a saved snapshot of *every file*, as of the form it had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.

The entire commit is read-only: no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.  Moreover, the stored files *inside* a commit are in a special, compressed and de-duplicated Git-only format, that only Git can *read*.  So not only are these files impossible to change, they're impossible for most programs on your computer to *use in any way at all*.  This means that before you can *use* a commit, you have to have Git *extract the archived files*.

This extraction is (mostly) what `git checkout` or `git switch` is about: you tell Git: *Remove all the files I extracted before, I'm no longer interested in* those *files.  Go to this other commit and extract* its *files.*  Now you have files you can *see* and *work with*, and even *change*.  These usable, work-able files are in what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree* (see also `git worktree`, available since Git 2.5).

Obviously, if there is some source archive for all the files, there must be *two* copies of each file: the one in the commit (archived and readable only by Git and writable by nobody—the way Git stores it, it might not even be a file), plus the one in your working tree (in normal everyday form: an actual *file*).  But there's a trick here.  There is a *third* "copy" of each file.  This extra copy—or "copy", in quotes—is in the *de-duplicated format*, but, unlike the copy in the commit, *can be replaced*.  And we should call this the *second* copy too: the first copy is in the commit, and this is the *second* copy of each file.  Because it's already de-duplicated, it's initially just re-using the committed copy.  The ordinary file in your working tree is thus the *third* copy—and it is always a *copy* since it's not in that Git-only de-duplicated format.

This second copy, that's in Git's internal format but is replaceable, lives in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  (This last form of the name mostly shows up as a flag, e.g., `git rm --cached` or `git diff --cached`).  When you use `git add` on a working tree file, Git:

- compresses the working tree file copy into Git's internal format;
- checks to see if that's a duplicate; and
- puts the right updated copy (new file, or re-use old duplicate) into Git's index.

When you run `git commit`, Git actually *makes* the commit snapshot from whatever is *in the index* at that time.  **This is why you must constantly `git add` files.**  You're telling Git: *Replace the index copy.*  This gets the updated working tree copy into Git's index, ready to be committed.  So saying that 6 files are "staged" really means: Of the (say) 400 files that would be in the next commit—that are in Git's index right now—394 are the same as the ones in the *current* commit, and 6 are *different* from the current commit.

Saying that 24 files are "unstaged" means: Of the (say) 400 files that are in Git's index, 376 (400 minus 24) match the normal-format file in my working tree, and 24 don't.

Note that since there *are* three copies of each file, it's possible to have both *staged changes* (the index copy of file `file.ext` differs from the committed copy) **and** *unstaged changes* (the working tree copy of `file.ext` differs from the to-be-committed index copy).  That's because *staged change* just means a difference in `HEAD`-vs-index: the *next* commit's copy of this file is updated.  *Unstaged change* just means a difference in index-vs-working-tree: you *could* `git add` this file and that would replace the index copy with the working tree copy (Git-ified for going into the *next*) commit.

What `git stash` does is:

- save the entire index set of files, as if in a commit: in fact, it *does* make a commit out of it, the way any commit works, except that the new commit is not on any branch; then
- for each file that exists in Git's index, `git add` the working tree file, and make a commit from *that* result as well, except that (once again) the new commit is not on any branch; then
- run `git reset --hard`.

This sequence is sometimes altered by options you provide to `git stash`, but that's the main sequence: Git makes *two commits*, on *no branch*, to save the index and working tree state, then uses `git reset --hard` to make the index and working tree match the current (`HEAD`) commit.

**Later**, when you go to *restore* the index and/or working tree with `git stash apply`, you must choose:

- *I'd like to apply only the working tree commit, completely ignoring the index commit:* this is `git stash apply`.  Or:
- *I'd like to apply both the working tree commit *and* the index commit:* this is `git stash apply --index`.

So Git always *saves* both, but at `apply` time you must *choose* whether to use the saved index, or not.  The default is "not".